# What do we know about the distribution of Mersenne primes?

Tags: prime-numbers

[Mersenne primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) are primes of the form $M_n = 2^n - 1$.  I'm wondering how far apart successive Mersenne primes can be.  For example, is $M_{n+1} \le O((M_n)^e)$?  Or, is $M_{n+1}$ always less than some power of $M_n$?  If not, how close together can successive Mesenne primes be in the worst case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not even known whether there are infinitely many Mersenne primes! There are *guesses* only, based on probabilistic assumptions for which there is no proof.

For a brief survey of some conjectural answers about the distribution of Mersenne primes, please see Wikipedia article on [Mersenne Conjectures.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_conjectures)

Answer (score 1):

Visualization and discussion of distribution of Mersenne primes is maintained by Chris K. Caldwell on his ["Where is the next Mersenne prime?"](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/NextMersenne.html) FAQ page.

Particularly, it discusses the Lenstra–Pomerance–Wagstaff conjecture:

> There are asymptotically $e^\gamma\log_2 \log{x} \approx 1.78\log_2\log{x} $ Mersenne primes less than $x$.

where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant.

(Interestingly, the formula predicts 45.9 Mersenne primes smaller than $2^{82,589,933}-1$, though this is actually 51st known Mersenne prime. So those primes currently appear more frequently than expected.)

The page also discusses the gaps between Mersenne primes.