# Is there an anomaly in the distribution of Mersenne primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers, distribution-of-primes, mersenne-numbers, computational-number-theory

In a recent [press release](https://www.mersenne.org/primes/?press=M82589933) off the Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search distributed computing project page, it is announced that
$$2^{82589933} - 1$$
is the largest known (Mersenne) prime, corresponding to the $51^{\text{st}}$ known even perfect number
$$2^{82589932}(2^{82589933} - 1).$$

According to GIMPS' press release:

> This is GIMPS' $12^{\text{th}}$ prime discovery between $2^{20000000}-1$ and $2^{85000000}-1$, *triple the expected number of new primes*. One reason to search for new primes is *to match actual results with expected results*. This anomaly is not necessarily evidence that existing theories on the distribution of Mersenne primes are incorrect. However, if the trend continues it may be worth further investigation.

[image]

Here are my questions:

> > **(1)** How is the expected number of new Mersenne primes computed?  Is there some underlying statistical model that is used?
> >
> > **(2)** What existing theories would be incorrect if there was indeed an anomaly in the distribution of Mersenne primes?

The following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/451895) appears to be related but this is not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: It is related to the theories derived from conjectures related to Mersenne primes, [here is a short article](https://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/heuristic.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, @rtybase!  Checking it out now... =)

Comment: @rtybase, if you could just further expound on your last comment with an actual (not just a link-only) answer, then I will be more than happy to accept it!  =)

Comment: It's Christmas coming, I have to entertain my family :). But if you found the link useful, I am glad I was helpful!

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris It is extremely hard to estimate the number of Mersenne primes in a range of huge exponents. Moreover, for events that are very unlikely (for example a huge number to be prime), it is not so unusual that we observe much more events than expected. The formula giving the number of Mersenne numbers will anyway only be a rough guess, we cannot expect that it is "accurate" , in particular the formula cannot prove the conjecture that infinite many Mersenne primes exist.

Comment: off-topic comment : A bit depressing how fast the records for the largest prime are broken.

Comment: @Peter I certainly agree with your first comment.  Perhaps I was trying to find an answer to the question of or to articulate the *anomaly* alluded to in the press release.  That being said, although I feel a bit sad that I do not get to discover the next Mersenne prime(s), I also feel encouraged to continue pursuing this research area, as this is closely related to my own works on odd perfect numbers.  (I invite you to check out [this arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.5616.pdf) as well as this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/48215), in case you have not yet done so already.)

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris For the sake of curiousity : How are ODD perfect numers related to Mersenne primes ?

Comment: @Peter: One of my (intractable) conjectures is that the Euler/special primes are in one-to-one correspondence with the odd perfect numbers in the same way that the Mersenne primes are in one-to-one correspondence with the even perfect numbers. Then another one of my conjectures is that the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture is in fact false, so that the Euler/special prime $q$ of an odd perfect number has exponent $k > 1$, while Mersenne primes $2^p - 1$ trivially have exponent one. Then the abundancy indices of $q^k$ and $2^p - 1$ satisfy certain inequalities.

Comment: @Peter:  I meant to say that "the abundancy indices of (the Euler factor) $q^k$ and (of the Mersenne prime) $2^p - 1$ satisfy certain *numerical* inequalities" in my last comment.